# php dynamically open multilevel directory using open_dir() function

Tags: php, opendir

I took over this site for management. the former developer used opendir() which opens only one level before getting the files in the folder. I would like to create multi-level folders before the final files. I created the sub-folders on the server but I need to modify the code to dynamically recognise the sub-folders as folders not file.

```
 if ($handle = opendir("parentfolder/".$pageid.'/')) {
        $list = array();
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                $list[] = "$file\n";
            }
        }
        rsort($list);
        $clength =  count($list);
        for($x = 0; $x <$clength; $x++){
            $pubFolders .= "<a href='".$maindomain."/reports/".$list[$x]."' class='imagefolders'><img src='".$maindomain."/images/icons/image.png' alt=''/><br>".$list[$x]."</a>";
        } 
        $data = $data.$pubFolders;
        closedir($handle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob()` with `GLOB_ONLYDIR`; some example functions are as follows:

```
function findDirectories($rootPath) {
    $directories = array();
    foreach (glob($rootPath . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $directory) {
        $directories[] = $directory;
    }
    return $directories;
}

function findFiles($rootPath, $extension) {
    $files = array();
    foreach (glob($rootPath . "/*.$extension") as $file) {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
    return $files;
}

function findFilesRecursive($rootPath,$extension) {
    $files = findFiles($rootPath,$extension);
    $directories = findDirectories($rootPath);
    if (!empty($directories)) {
        foreach ($directories as $key=>$directory) {
            $foundFiles = findFilesRecursive($directory,$extension);
            foreach ($foundFiles as $foundFile) {
                $files[] = $foundFile;
            }
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

If you don't care about defining specific extensions, just pass in `*` as the `$extension` parameter.

Comment: Thanks David. Will test and revert